# timeout on aws load balancer connected to fargate cluster -- infrastructure defined via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate, terraform-cloud

I have a simple nodejs container that's currently in the 'websockets-server' registry. I have downloaded this image from AWS ECR and ran it locally to confirm that the health check works on the container itself.

Unfortunately, when I attempt to hit the URL for the load balancer or the domain I assigned its dns as an alias -- the connection times out.

I'm pretty sure it's because of my configuration but can't find the missing piece.

ECS fargate cluster, service and task:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "websocket-server-cluster" {
  name = "websocket-server-cluster"
}


resource "aws_ecs_service" "websocket-server-service" {
  name                               = "websocket-server-service"
  cluster                            = aws_ecs_cluster.websocket-server-cluster.arn
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 0
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.websocket-server-task.arn

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.websocket-server.arn
    container_name   = "websocket-server"
    container_port   = 8080

  }

  network_configuration {
    assign_public_ip = true
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.public.id]
    subnets          = [aws_subnet.public.id]
  }

}

module "websocket-server" {
  source           = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-ecs-container-definition.git?ref=tags/0.58.1"
  container_name   = "websocket-server"
  container_image  = "${aws_ecr_repository.websocket-server.repository_url}:latest"
  container_cpu    = "256"
  container_memory = "512"
  port_mappings = [
    {
      containerPort = 8080
      hostPort      = 8080
      protocol      = "TCP"
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "websocket-server-task" {
  family                   = "websocket-server"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  memory                   = "512"
  cpu                      = "256"
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs-container-role.arn
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs-container-role.arn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  container_definitions    = module.websocket-server.json_map_encoded_list
}
```

Load balancer and listeners:

```
resource "aws_lb" "main" {
  name                       = "main"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.public.id]
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  subnets                    = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.public-backup.id]
}


resource "aws_lb_target_group" "websocket-server" {
  name        = "websocket-server"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    enabled             = true
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 3
    timeout             = 10
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    path                = "/apis/websocket-server/health"
    interval            = "100"
    matcher             = "200"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.main
  ]

}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "websocket-server" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.main.arn


  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.websocket-server.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.main.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}
```

vpc and security groups:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/18"

  tags = {
    Name = "Main VPC"
  }
}

# PUBLIC SUBNET
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/27"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet"
  }
}

# PRIVATE SUBNET
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "public-backup" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.32/27"

  availability_zone = "eu-west-2b"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Backup Subnet"
  }
}


resource "aws_internet_gateway" "main" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}


### PUBLIC SECURITY GROUP
resource "aws_security_group" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  name   = "public"

  tags = {
    name = "Public Security Group"
  }
}

### outbound rules
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_out" {
  type        = "egress"
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 0
  protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}

### inbound rules
# ssh
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_in_ssh" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 22
  to_port     = 22
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}
# http
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_in_http" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 80
  to_port     = 80
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}
# https
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "public_in_https" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 443
  to_port     = 443
  protocol    = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}


### PRIVATE SECURITY GROUP
resource "aws_security_group" "private" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  name   = "private"

  tags = {
    name = "Private Security Group"
  }
}

### outbound rules
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "private_out" {
  type        = "egress"
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 0
  protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.private.id
}

### inbound rules
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "private_in" {
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = 0
  to_port     = 65535
  protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.main.cidr_block]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.public.id
}
```

Comment: Could be because your target group uses port 80, and your container is 8080.

Comment: Ah, I'm used to GCPs cloud run not caring about that -- would I need to change just aws_lb_target_group and aws_lb_listener ports from 80 to 8080 to listen for HTTP? 

I'm giving that a try right away and looking into how I could re-map those ports or perhaps in the future expose port 80 on them.

Comment: @Marcin so I have that listener for the HTTP port that redirects to HTTPS -- do I need to set the container port to 443 to be able to access it?

Comment: Changed them all to 443 -- unfortunately same timeout result

Comment: What port does your software running in the container actually listen to? That's the port that the container and target group need to be configured with. The load balancer should only be configured to listen on ports 80/443, and forward traffic to the target group. The target group will forward the traffic to whatever port it is configured with. All the ports don't have to match (and usually don't).

Comment: @MarkB in my long journey trying to eliminate most factors, I've made sure to make a deployment with a container version that is listening on port 443, download the actual image available in ECR and run it locally to confirm it is behaving as expected, and it does. 

I've seen other tutorials/examples where if there are issues with the LB accessing the container, it still registers the 5xx error on the 'monitor' tab -- but in my case, there's nothing registering -- no requests getting to the load balancer at all.

Comment: What happens if you spin up an EC2 instance, with public IP assigned, in the same subnet as the load balancer? Can you SSH into that instance's public IP? If not, your subnets are misconfigured. Also, you haven't made any modifications to the default VPC Network ACL settings have you?

Comment: Also, are you trying to access the load balancer via a custom domain name you have setup? Have you tried using the DNS name that Amazon gives the load balancer?

Comment: I'm not using the default VPC network and haven't touched that, I'm using the VPC configured above for all resources involved. 

I'll try to spin up an EC2 instance with that container and see if I can access it, I'm trying to access the load balancer purely via the DNS name that amazon gives the load balancer.

My current hypothesis is that the VPC/subnets are misconfigured so I included all my subnet/vpc/security group definitions in the post above

Comment: I never asked about the default VPC network. I asked about the default Network ACLs that are created when you create a VPC. If you haven't touched them, then that's good.